# EOL error. In python cricket game

Tags: python

*Please note that this is an excerpt. The elif DOES have an if before it when in the full chunk of code. The game worked untill i decided to add a random choice, about how the player got out*

```
    import random
    howout = ['Bowled', 'Run-out', 'Caught', 'Stumped', 'LBW',]


    elif playruns == 5:
                               playouts = playouts + 1
                               print("Your player is out!",random.choice(howout),)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a floating comma before your final close-parentheses.

```
print("Your player is out!",random.choice(howout),)
                                     remove this ^
```

Comment: Thats it. Thanks. I will mark it as answered in T-3 minutes.